# array variable in a div tag replicates in all the other div tags in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-init, ng-init

The array `ar` array in first #div1 is repeated in all the div.
All other div have the common array variable name `ar`. I tried with different names.

```
<body ng-app="">  
    <div id="div1" ng-init="ar=['java','j2ee','c','c++','spring','hibernate']">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item1 in ar">
                {{item1}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" ng-init="ar=['books','pens','eraser''sharpner','scale','scale']">
        <table border="1">
            <tr ng-repeat="item2 in ar">
                <td>{{item2}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div> <br/>
    <div id="div3" ng-init="ar=['html','css','angularjs''PHP','BOOTSTRAP','NODEJS']">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>sl.no.</th>
                <th>courses</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="item3 in ar">
                <td>{{$index}}</td>
                <td>{{item3}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="div4" ng-repeat="item4 in ar">
        {{item4}}
    </div>
</body>

<script src="angular.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in static values, you may skip keeping the array variables like `ar` altogether and pass the arrays directly.

```
<li ng-repeat="item1 in ['java','j2ee','c','c++','spring','hibernate']">
    {{item1}}
</li>
```

and

```
<tr ng-repeat="item2 in ['books','pens','eraser''sharpner','scale','scale'] ">
    <td>{{item2}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the comma

```
<div id="div2" ng-init="ar=['books','pens','eraser''sharpner','scale','scale']">

<div id="div3" ng-init="ar=['html','css','angularjs''PHP','BOOTSTRAP','NODEJS']">
```

Another thing, using the same variable name each time it is initialized, those referenced elements that use the new value.

You could try, define each list with a name different variable, look up this

```
<body ng-app="">
   <div id="div1" ng-init="ar=['java','j2ee','c','c++','spring','hibernate']">
      <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="item1 in ar">
            {{item1}}
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="div2" ng-init="br=['books','pens','eraser','sharpner','scale','scale']">
      <table border="1">
         <tr ng-repeat="item2 in br">
            <td>{{item2}}</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div id="div3" ng-init="cr=['html','css','angularjs','PHP','BOOTSTRAP','NODEJS']">
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>sl.no.</th>
            <th>courses</th>
         </tr>
         <tr ng-repeat="item3 in cr">
            <td>{{$index}}</td>
            <td >{{item3}}</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div id="div4" ng-repeat="item4 in ar" >
      {{item4}}
   </div>
</body>
```

and here you have in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jenhyj2z/)